# Enter key press event for document with a drop-down list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a html with more than one select drop down list and input. When the <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed, I want to call a button trigger function, but when I press down list, its not called any event function. I tried to button `type ="submit"` but it not working.

How do I calling trigger function when the <kbd>enter</kbd> key is pressed?

The following code works for selectbox, but it does not work for dropdown.

```
jQuery(document).keypress(function (e) {

    if (e.key == "Enter") {
        $("#button").trigger('click');
        e.key = null;
    }
});
```

or

```
 jQuery(document).keypress(function (e) {

 if (e.which == 13) {
         $("#button").trigger('click');
        return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Just as a side note, you might want to consider using `(...).on('keyup', function(){...})`  instead as `keypress/keydown` is triggered while holding the key down over and over, while keyup is triggered only when the key is let go. If you do need it on keydown then implement a "hasbeenpressed=true" logic or you bombard your click. - Also, I'm not sure what you mean by works select but not dropdown. Please post both HTML mark up examples in a working [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using the code snipped feature to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by drop down as a <select> element is a drop down to me? Can you show us what the HTML looks like?